# Sorting dictionary in Python (AA must come after Z)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
mydict = {
    'Column A':'test',
    'Column S': 'NORMAL',
    'Column C': 'test',
    'Column AA': 'non-Gurantee',
    'Column Z': 'SAMPLE',
    'Column F': 'STANDARD'
}
```

Looking to sort this dictionary with AA coming after Z. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the items in the dictionary according to the length of the keys (you didn't specify if this is what you are looking for but in addition, I also sorted them by lexical order)
This should do the trick :

```
mydict  = {    'Column A':'test',
    'Column S': 'NORMAL',
    'Column C': 'test',
    'Column AA': 'non-Gurantee',
    'Column Z': 'SAMPLE',
    'Column F': 'STANDARD'
}
k = dict(sorted(mydict .items(),key=lambda x: (len(x[0]), x[0])))
print(k)
```

output:

```
{'Column A': 'test', 'Column C': 'test', 'Column F': 'STANDARD', 'Column S': 'NORMAL', 'Column Z': 'SAMPLE', 'Column AA': 'non-Gurantee'}
```